# How to communicate through laptop Ethernet port through Virtual Box Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to send out ping requests through the ethernet port of my laptop to my device attached to it with a LAN cable. But I want to do it from a virtual box Ubuntu running on my windows 10. Is that possible?

Comment: virtual machines normally have access to the internet, so, yes it is possible

Comment: Yes but how to connect my VM to the physical ethernet port of the laptop?

Comment: there are many tutorials for that ... this site is a last resort if you are stuck ... please do research first and attempt a connection ... do not come here first to ask a question

Comment: @jsotola I did a search and all I could find was making a connection of the VM with your laptop's wireless network adapter. 
I could not find directions on how to connect to my laptop's ethernet port. Maybe there is an example out there but I don't understand the terminology yet.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=win10+virtual+box+network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this steps:

1. On Virtual Box, select the ubuntu virtal machine
2. Go to the VM's settings > Network
3. Select the network adapter that you want to modify (usualy Adapter 1)
4. Ensure that the "Enable Network Adapter" option is selected
5. In the option "Attached to" select "Bridged Adapter"
6. The menu "Name" will appear and you have to select your ethernet card. The device's names are usually self-explanatory, in my case i have the adapter "Intel(R) 1211 Gigabit Network" which corresponds to my ethernet adapter.
7. Click on the ok button to save the changes.

You will have to configure static ip addresses on both your virtual machine and the other device if you connected your laptop to the other device directly with a cable. This may not be necessary if your laptop and the other device are connected to your home modem.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! Such simple easy to follow answers are really helpful for beginners like me who don't understand the jargon of the field.

Comment: Hi I can confirm that this method worked. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!! @user2005651